# Surface area of a hexagon

Tags: c, geometry

I am currently attempting to learn C, and have made this program to calculate the area of a regular hexagon:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(){
int a;
float ans;
scanf("%d", &a); // get length of side

ans = ((pow(a, (1/3)))/2)*(a*a);

printf("%f", ans);
}
```

However, it outputs seemingly random numbers.

Comment: You have integer operations in your calculations. The expression `1/3` will *always* be zero for example.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, you're missing some semicolons. Also, your formula is wrong: the area of a hexagon with edge length `a` can be calculated as `A = (3 / 2) a² * √3`, which is achieved by the following code: `ans = (3 * sqrt(3) / 2)*(a*a);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your code doesn't compile (`Missing semicolon`) and also you should use `int main()` instead of `void main()`.

Secondly your formula also wrong, the area of a regular hexagon of side length `a` is calculated as `((3√3)/2)*a²`.

Thirdly Expression like `1/3` always yield zero as both are integer, to get expected behavior make one of them float/double. like `1.0/3` or `(float)1/3` etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int  main()
{
    int a;
    float ans;
    scanf("%d", &a); // get length of side
    ans  = (3*sqrt(3)/2.0)*a*a;
    printf("%f", ans);
}
```